# Can I set a custom horizontal width for a Gnome panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

Is there some way to specify a custom size for a Gnome panel? I'm using Gnome Classic on ubuntu 12.04. There is an "expand" option, but I want to exactly specify the size of the panel. I'm not talking about the height, but rather the width of a horizontal panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set a custom horizontal width for a Gnome Panel. The best you can do is disable the "expand" property, and let it adjust to the size of its contents; you can also change the "x-centered" property to center the panel or keep it on the left.

This can be done with `dconf-editor` (install `dconf-tools`), with the settings found in `top-panel` or `bottom-panel` under (see top panel in screenshot):

```
org->gnome->gnome-panel->layout->toplevels
```

[image]

Comment: That's too bad, but thanks for explaning it :) I wanted this because my desktop is spanned across three monitors. I guess I'll just stick with a single huge panel at the top.

Comment: @KalleElmér, yes, it's a bug/"feature" that has been brought up numerous times, but that the Gnome team cannot/does not want to fix. But disabling expand might work for you, right, if it keeps the bar only on the center monitor?  Please add a comment if you have any more questions, and don't forget to upvote the answer :)